# virtual-dom diff Replace/Remove Rather Than Only Remove

Tags: javascript, virtual-dom

Using the [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) `h` and `diff` methods.

Given: `[a,b]` and `[b]`

The resulting `diff` patch replaces `a` with `b` then removes `b`, rather than simply removing `a`.

[RequireBin example.](http://requirebin.com/?gist=a1fe075b4553c3b44354657c1d6625d5)

```
vdom1 = h('div', [
  h('div', 'div stuff'),
  h('img', {src: 'keepme.png'})
])

vdom2 = h('div', [
  h('img', {src: 'keepme.png'})
])

diff(vdom1, vdom2)
```

Results in:

```
1 VNODE DIV ... IMG (replace DIV with IMG)
3 REMOVE IMG
```

What needs to be done to "align" the `img` elements so it is not removed and added back in?

Comment: You know what's funny is I was just thinking about how to make this work using virtual-dom. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) property [`key`](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/tree/master/virtual-hyperscript#key) as an element attribute solves exactly this.

> [key](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/tree/master/virtual-hyperscript#key)
>
> If you call h with h('div', { key: someKey }) it will set a key on the
>   return VNode. This key is not a normal DOM property but is a
>   virtual-dom optimization hint.
>
> It basically tells virtual-dom to re-order DOM nodes instead of
>   mutating them.

[Fixed example.](http://requirebin.com/?gist=chrisinajar/0d5e8d8346ac420ea76c1eab8b673db5)

```
vdom1 = h('div', [
  h('div', 'div stuff'),
  h('img', {src: 'keepme.png', key: 1})
])

vdom2 = h('div', [
  h('img', {src: 'keepme.png', key: 1})
])

diff(vdom1, vdom2)
```

Results in:

```
1 REMOVE DIV
```

(Credit goes to [Chris Vickery](https://github.com/chrisinajar) for the [solution](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/issues/388#issuecomment-220406537).)